# Select many to many with hierarchical table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
   dbo.Tags
   ---------------
   [TagsId]

   dbo.TagsDetail 
   ----------------
   [TagsDetailId] 
   [TagsId]
   [TagsGroupId]

   dbo.TagsGroup (hierarchical table with 2 level)
   ----------------
   [TagsGroupId]
   [ParentId]


    Tags
    +--------+
    | Tagsld |
    +--------+
    | 1      |
    | 2      | 
    +--------+


    TagsDetails
    +-------------+-----------+
    | Tagsld      |TagsGroupId|
    +-------------+-----------+
    | 1           | 1         | 
    | 2           | 2         | 
    +-------------+-----------+

    TagsGroup
    +-------------+-----------+
    | TagsGroupId | ParentId  |
    +-------------+-----------+
    | 1           | null      | 
    | 2           | null      | 
    | 3           | 1         |
    +-------------+-----------+
```

Input TagGroupsId = 2 => all taggroup(1, 2, 3)

How can I select all related TagsGroupIds by input one @TagsGroupId?

I tried to solved by selecting all TagsDetailIds by @TagsGroupId so I find all TagsIds and from TagsIds.  I found all TagsDetailIds and then get all relate TagsGroupIds and it's descendants and on each TagsGroupId, I started a loop again.

I don't know where I can stop to make sure I have selected all TagsGroupId.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I have added the value, can you help me

Comment: yes im working on it.

Comment: Not cleat to me.  Why do you repeat Tag on every column name?

Comment: why do you get (1, 2, 3) tag group 2 has no children or parents.  Are you missing some example data?

Comment: also TagGroupId 3 is not in TagsDetails table.

Comment: @paparazzo because Tags and TagsGroup have n - n relationship by using TagsDetails table in the middle

Comment: What does that have to do with Tags on every column name?   Question is still not clear to me.

Comment: @paparazzo -- why is the question not clear because of column names -- names can be anything.

Comment: @Hogan You think the column names confused me?  Moving on.

Comment: @paparazzo -- yes I do because that is what you said "Not cleat to me. Why do you repeat Tag on every column name?"

Comment: @Hogan Personally I still don't think it's clear what the expected input or output is

Comment: @Tom -- that is totally true.  I made a guess based on the ~5-10 times I seen a data model and requirement like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Using plurals is not typically how this is done -- so the column should be called TagId not TagsId and the table should be called TagGroup not TagsGroup.  Just easier this way.  It has no effect but that is the style convention everyone uses.

So as I understand it, a tag group can have up to two parents and can have children and grand children.

You can do it all in one query (with sub queries and joins) but I think a CTE will make the logic easier.

```
WITH Parent AS
(
   SELECT TD.TagId
   FROM TagGroup TG
   JOIN TagDetail ON TD.TagGroupId = TG.ParentId
   WHERE TG.TagGroupId = @TagGroupId
), GrandParent AS
(
   SELECT TD.TagId
   FROM TagGroup TG
   JOIN TagDetail ON TD.TagGroupId = TG.ParentId
   WHERE TG.TagGroupId = (SELECT TagId FROM Parent) 
), Child AS
(
   SELECT TD.TagId
   FROM TagGroup TG
   JOIN TagDetail ON TD.TagGroupId = TG.TagGroupId
   WHERE TG.ParentId = @TagGroupId 
), GrandChild AS
(
   SELECT TD.TagId
   FROM TagGroup TG
   JOIN TagDetail ON TD.TagGroupId = TG.TagGroupId
   WHERE TG.ParentId = (SELECT TagId FROM Child) 
)
SELECT TagId 
FROM Parent
UNION
SELECT TagId
FROM GrandParent
UNION
SELECT TagId
FROM Child
UNION
SELECT TagId
FROM GrandChild
```